Show that quadratic form is surjective
Let $2\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{F}$, i.e. $\mathbb{F}$ is not of characteristic $2$.
Let $q: V\to \mathbb{F}$ be a quadratic form associated to a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form. If there exists $x\neq 0\in V$ such that $q(x)=0$, show that $q$ is surjective.

If there exists $x\neq 0\in V$ such that $q(x)=0,$ then $q(x)=f(x,x)=0.$ This implies that $f(x,kx)=kf(x,x)=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{F}$.
For all $a\in\mathbb{F}$,
$$q(ax+y)=f(ax+y,ax+y)\\
=a^2f(x,x)+af(x,y)+af(y,x)+f(y,y)\\
=2af(x,y)+ q(y).$$
To obtain the last line of this equality I have used the fact that $f$ is symmetric.

So far this is what I have done, but I don't see how to conclude that $q$ is surjective from this.

Another thing that worries me is that I haven't used the fact that $f$ is non-degenerate.



Since $f$ is non-degenerate and $x\ne0$, there exists $y\in V$ such that $b:=f(x,y)\ne0$. Your calculation then shows that the range of $q$ contains
$$q(y)+2b\mathbb F=\mathbb F.$$

Wow, thanks! It makes sense now.
